# How can I use ES6/ES2015 with live reloading with Apache Cordova?

Tags: ios, cordova, cordova-plugins

I have been using ES6/ES2015 for a project, transpiling to ES5 via Babel(ify) and bundling with Browserify all via budo. This provides a nice workflow wherein a change to a ES6 file is detected, transpiling, and incremental bundling are done in memory without any file I/O and the browser is told to refresh.

I am new to Cordova and am trying to get a similar workflow working where the browser is replaced with the native iOS/Android in-app browser reloading on changes.

I've setup my config.xml to have a content element using  "http://192.168.1.8:9966/index.html" which is the IP of my laptop running budo.

I think there's a "cordova prepare" needed somewhere but I'm not sure how to integrate this or if budo needs to have copies of cordova.js or something.  That I am fuzzy on...

- https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/5.1.1/config_ref/index.html#link-1
- https://github.com/mattdesl/budo
- https://babeljs.io/
- http://browserify.org/

Plugins being used:

```
com.telerik.plugins.wkwebview 0.6.5 "WKWebView Polyfill"
cordova-plugin-battery-status 1.1.0 "Battery"
cordova-plugin-camera 1.2.0 "Camera"
cordova-plugin-console 1.0.1 "Console"
cordova-plugin-dialogs 1.1.1 "Notification"
cordova-plugin-file 3.0.0 "File"
cordova-plugin-file-transfer 1.3.0 "File Transfer"
cordova-plugin-geolocation 1.0.1 "Geolocation"
cordova-plugin-globalization 1.0.1 "Globalization"
cordova-plugin-inappbrowser 1.0.1 "InAppBrowser"
cordova-plugin-network-information 1.0.1 "Network Information"
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 2.1.0 "Splashscreen"
cordova-plugin-webserver 1.0.3 "CordovaWebServer"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.0.0 "Whitelist"
```

I have no errors in the iOS simulator log (Debug > System Log).

*Anyone have live reload working for ES6 and Cordova?* Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

*OK I figured this out. No one seems to be going this route but it's pretty awesome.*

### Live Reload with Cordova via Budo, Babel, and Browserify

#### Assumptions

- your dev machine has an IP of 192.168.1.8
- your app's entry point or main file is `src/main.js`
- your Cordova app's root dir is `app`

---

#### Budo

Run [budo](https://github.com/mattdesl/budo). Budo will also inject a script tag that talks to its LiveReload server. All of your transpiled and bundled ES5 code will be served will be from path "js/bundle.js".

```
budo src/main.js:js/bundle.js \
--dir=app/www \
--live="app/www/**/*" \
-t babelify | garnish
```

---

#### Config.xml

**Development version**

Update your Cordova app's config.xml, setting the *content* element's *src* property to load the app content (e.g. index.html) from your budo instance instead of the local filesystem.

```
<content src="http://192.168.1.8:9966/index.html" />
```

**Production version**

```
<content src="index.html" />
```

This loads the config from the filesystem as normal.

---

#### Index.html

Split your `app/www/index.html` file into 2 versions: development and production.  Switch between them with a shell script or similar.

Both versions of index.html reference `js/bundle.js` via a script tag.

**Development index.html**

The development version of index.html needs to load the `cordova.js` and `cordova_plugins.js` as well.

In my case, I am using iOS9 and the [Telerik plugin that enables WKWebView](https://github.com/Telerik-Verified-Plugins/WKWebView).  This plugin serves assets with an internal httpd to workaround an iOS bug and can be found at `http://localhost:1234`.  Thus, I simply load `cordova.js` and `cordova_plugins.js` from there.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:12344/cordova.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:12344/cordova_plugins.js"></script>
```

Thus, your development index.html should have a Content Security Policy that allows for all of these things to be loaded.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self'; script-src 'self' http://localhost:12344 http://192.168.1.8:*; connect-src 'self' ws://192.168.1.8:*" />
```

In other cases (e.g. Android), you will likely have to fiddle with symlinks and hooks.

**Production index.html**

You only need to load the `js/bundle.js` and do not need the Content Security Policy entries that reference `192.168.1.8`.

---

#### Live Reload / Making Changes

When you edit a ES2015 file referenced (in)directly by `src/main.js`, Budo will notice the change, transpile, bundle, and then notify the client via a WebSockets connection created the LiveReload injected script.

Make changes to `app/www/css/index.css` (or use SASS/LESS etc and have those write to index.css). Budo will notice and will send down changes to be realized without a page reload.

Make changes to `app/www/index.html` and Budo will notice and send those changes down via its LiveReload server.

---

#### Notes

- `deviceready` will only fire once as you might expect, not on every change to a ES2015 file.
- Adding/removing plugins or changes to config.xml are to be realized with a rebuild: `cordova run ios`.
- If you periodically see a file being cached after a build, clean the project and rebuild: `cordova clean ios`.

---

#### Telerik's WKWebView Plugin

If you are using the Telerik WKWebView plugin, use the latest from github instead of NPM.

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/Telerik-Verified-Plugins/WKWebView
```

There's a bug in the plugin code currently that mishandles loading of http-based `content` (start page).  I have a [pull request](https://github.com/Telerik-Verified-Plugins/WKWebView/issues/186) for this pending (Oct 27 2015).

Answer (score 0):

@Johnny,
Welcome to the Cordova/Phonegap world. The answer you are looking for is to use the ["hooks"](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/5.1.1/guide/appdev/hooks/index.html). This was design so you can add stuff to your workflow.

You can add or control, I quote:

```
before_build
before_clean
before_compile
before_docs
before_emulate
before_platform_add
before_platform_rm/
before_platform_ls
:::
before_prepare
(and more)
```

You should also read: [Top Mistakes by Developers new to Cordova/Phonegap](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/new-to-Phonegap.md)

I am updating it next weekend. This weekend I am working on a blog on `whitelist`, which has become a thorn in development.

FWIW: I am also working on a `web components` blog, but it is weeks away.
My main blog is: http://codesnippets.altervista.org/blog/

On **live reload** there are several developments right now. Phonegap has one named "hydration". Iconic has one, and so does MobileFirst (IBM). Right now a decent working "live reload" is badly needed. I have not had time to check any of the newer ones (whos names don't come to mind)

Best of Luck

Comment: How would hooks drive live-reload?  I am looking for a solution to this: change ES6 file, auto-transpile, auto-refresh in Cordova app with minimal overhead... Browserify takes 6-10 seconds for a full re-bundling of my project but budo+browserify in memory does it incrementally which is near instant.

Comment: Also Hydration doesn't seem to be live reload at all. It's an app auto-update mechanism which fires after a new build is created. I'm trying to avoid re-building entirely.

Comment: @JohnnyServers, Ahh, you want to do a "live-reload", ala codepen or jsfiddle. Yes. Hydration does a full rebuild, so a bit short of what you ant. The problem with implementing on a mobile device is that the App is bundled in an APK - the equivalent of a `.zip`. The same with iOS. This is not to say a single webpage cannot be done.  --- I believe your target is to do it in a emulator. The "hooks" can help you because it lays out the process. You in turn can short circuit the process. Beyond pointing you to place to look, there is not much I can do. Feel free to ask, I do a lot of reading.

Comment: FWIW, you may want to add the *"live-reload", ala codepen or jsfiddle* to make it clear to other people.